# Does the atmosphere rotate slightly slower than the earth surface?

Tags: atmospheric-science, coriolis-effect

I often hear the vague explanation that the Coriolis Effect is why air rotates into pressure systems. That doesn't explain it for me though.

Is pressure gradient directly toward the center of the low? And does the air turn only because the pressure system itself is turning? And is that not just due to friction with the surface where the surface is moving faster at a point at the Equator than toward the poles?

1. Where does Coriolis come into that?
2. I'm assuming that there is some kind of friction or force/acceleration of some kind (gravity of the sun on the atmosphere?) slowing the atmosphere down slightly compared to the earth's surface, so that the latitudinal difference in friction with the surface explains rotation of pressure systems. Is this correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be due to friction with the surface (or friction with lower layers of air, which in turn experience friction from even lower layers of air, and so on, until the bottom layer is driven by friction from the surface)?

Comment: Indeed.. that is what I mean.. but that assumes some form of friction opposing the transfered ground friction.. otherwise the upper layers, if nothing else was effecting them, would have long since accelerated to the same speed as the lower layers/ground

Comment: I think you might be conflating a few things here.  The air moving with the surface of the Earth is different than the Coriolis effect.  The question in the title and the body of your question seem completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure gradient is toward the center of the low.  That's pretty much what a low pressure area means.

On a flat and non-rotating Earth, that pressure gradient would drive air to move straight toward the center of the low.  But Earth is both spherical and rotating...

Imagine a bit of air directly to the north of the center of the low in the northern hemisphere.  (The air is in Chicago, and the air is somewhat south of that) Because Earth is *rotating*, that air is already moving around Earth's axis eastward at the velocity that'll take it around that axis every 24 hours.  Now the pressure moves it south.  But it keeps that same eastward velocity.  As it moves south, because Earth is *round*, it's now farther from the axis:  It's not moving east fast enough to get all the way around the axis in 24 hours.  Put another way, the air to the south is moving east *faster*, and the air from Chicago falls behind:  It moves west, or turns to the right.

[image]

Note that a bit of air that has to move north to get to the low has the opposite problem:  It's moving closer to the axis, so it's going too fast.   It'll pull out in front of the air already there and move east.  But that's again a right turn, because it's moving north.

How about some air west of the low?  To catch up to the center of the low, it has to go *faster* than the surrounding air.  It's moving *faster* around the axis. The resulting centrifugal force is directly away from the axis, not away from the center of Earth because Earth is *round*. That means it has a component to the south, to the right, and pushes the air in that direction.

[image]

Friction has no part in causing any of this.

Comment: If the atmosphere weren't rotating along with the Earth, this wouldn't happen. Isn't friction between the surface and the atmosphere what keeps the atmosphere rotating along with the Earth? Otherwise, turbulence would cause the large-scale rotation of the atmosphere to eventually dissipate into a bunch of smaller-scale motions, right?

Comment: "If the atmosphere weren't rotating along with the Earth", nobody would care about this effect because 1000mph winds would scour the surface down to bed rock.  But of course that's not the case, because the atmosphere does rotate with the earth on average.  Winds are the (very small by comparison) variations from that.  To put it another way, nothing is needed to "keep() the atmosphere rotating along with the Earth". It does that anyway.

Comment: Those 1000mph winds would eventually stop once enough angular momentum is transferred from the Earth to the atmosphere. The atmosphere pushes on the Earth and the Earth pushes on the atmosphere. It's precisely this transfer mechanism that I'm saying shouldn't be neglected, as without it, the atmosphere would not be kept rotating along with the Earth. You can call it what you want; I call it "friction" because it's a partially-dissipative interaction that happens at the boundary between two objects when they are traveling at different local velocities.

Comment: You may have a different word for this interaction, and that's fine, but unequivocally saying that "friction has no part in causing any of this" without defining specifically what you mean by "friction" may cause confusion.

Comment: "To put it another way, nothing is needed to "keep() the atmosphere rotating along with the Earth". It does that anyway." - So you're saying that, once you stir a cup of tea, it will keep flowing round and round forever?

Comment: "once you stir a cup of tea, it will keep flowing round and round forever?" is a different case from the Earth.  If you rotate a cup of tea, once the tea was moving with the rotating cup, that would go on forever.  Yes, friction was needed to get the atmosphere moving with the Earth, but now it is; to say "without (friction), the atmosphere would not be kept rotating along with the Earth" is just wrong. What force would cause that? The OP's confusion is due to incorrectly considering friction as why "air rotates into pressure systems", which is really just the Coriolis force

Comment: Thanks.. so the "coriolis effect" is just a confusing name conservation of momentum.. this is a brilliant and intuitive explanation.. thanks!.. it explains why sub-tropical pressure systems move Eastward, and the general airflow at the equator is Westward

Comment: I still wonder if there is any other forces slowing the atmosphere relative to the Earth's surface (opposing surface friction), or if the Westerly airflow at the Equator is 100% accounted for by Coriolis (slower air moving toward the Equator)

Comment: Large scale circulation, I.e wind belts and Hadley cells see. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell ) involve significant amounts of energy transfer due to heating & cooling. That would drive north-south flows which the Coriolis forced turn into east-west flows.

Comment: @probably_someone, you've asked some very good questions, but they're only here in the comments.  I suggest that you post them as real (separate) questions (possibly with a link back to this one).